# Checking if a list contains a sublist

Tags: python

I'm working on the following practice problem from codingbat:

> Given an array of ints, return True if .. 1, 2, 3, .. appears in the array somewhere.

I've written:

```
def array123(nums):
    array = [1,2,3]
    for i in nums:
        sub = nums[i:i+3] 
        if array == sub:
            return True
     return False
```

It keeps failing when the string is [1,2,3], any other combination of numbers works.  I understand the solution codingbat gives, but I don't understand why my code is only failing in that instance.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because `for` doesn't work how you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for i in nums:` successively assigns to `i` the value of the **items** of list `nums`.

However you appear to believe it's assigning **indices** rather than **value** -- perhaps that's because it's what it the equivalent construct would to in Javascript.

So make `i` iterate over the **indices** -- `for i in range(len(nums)-3):` and the rest of your code seems fine!